# How do I standardize a matrix?

Tags: python, algorithm, math, numpy

Basically, take a matrix and change it so that its mean is equal to 0 and variance is 1. I'm using numpy's arrays so if it can already do it it's better, but I can implement it myself as long as I can find an algorithm.

edit: nvm nimrodm has a better implementation

Comment: Define "change". What if, say, we just replace the matrix with the identity matrix or something? What kinds of transformations are OK?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need to do this?

Comment: I'm trying to implement a computer vision algorithm that asks for this operation to be performed in the intermediate steps. I think it's because it's a requirement for PCA but I'm not sure.

Comment: Would you consider accepting the answer by @nimrodm so I can delete mine?

Answer (score 78):

The following subtracts the mean of A from each element (the new mean is 0), then normalizes the result by the standard deviation.

```
import numpy as np
A = (A - np.mean(A)) / np.std(A)
```

The above is for standardizing the entire matrix as a whole,  If A has many dimensions and you want to standardize each column individually, specify the [axis](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.std.html):

```
import numpy as np
A = (A - np.mean(A, axis=0)) / np.std(A, axis=0)
```

Always verify by hand what these one-liners are doing before integrating them into your code.  A simple change in orientation or dimension can drastically change (silently) what operations numpy performs on them.

Comment: you may want to update `A` only where `std(A) > 0` to avoid division by zero and `NaN` values

Comment: Is this possible where A is represented as a list of lists?

Comment: @Neamah Why not just [convert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346336/list-of-lists-into-numpy-array) to a numpy array?

Comment: Adding to @nimrodm's answer, this can be implemented in numpy as follows
import numpy as np
meanArr = np.mean(A)
standardized_arr = (A-meanArr)/np.std(A)

Answer (score 13):

```
import scipy.stats as ss

A = np.array(ss.zscore(A))
```

Answer (score 6):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

standardized_data = StandardScaler().fit_transform(your_data)
```

Example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

>>> data = np.random.randint(25, size=(4, 4))
>>> data
array([[17, 12,  4, 17],
       [ 1, 16, 19,  1],
       [ 7,  8, 10,  4],
       [22,  4,  2,  8]])

>>> standardized_data = StandardScaler().fit_transform(data)
>>> standardized_data
array([[ 0.63812398,  0.4472136 , -0.718646  ,  1.57786412],
       [-1.30663482,  1.34164079,  1.55076242, -1.07959124],
       [-0.57735027, -0.4472136 ,  0.18911737, -0.58131836],
       [ 1.24586111, -1.34164079, -1.02123379,  0.08304548]])
```

Works well on large datasets.

Comment: you could use ctrl+k to indent everything instead of backticks.

Comment: Forgive me if i ask a stupid question, But I thought the moment we start doing standardization, the values of our data should be between 0 and 1. and nothing should go beyond the 1. in the example you have just given, I can see some values like 1.57786412 .... is it the right way

Comment: @kaybrian I don't believe that's the correct [definition](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-standardize-matrix-elements-in-r#:~:text=The%20standardization%20is%20the%20process,elements%2C%20we%20can%20use%20data.) The standardization is the process of converting a value to another value so that the mean of the set of values from which the original value was taken becomes zero and the standard deviation becomes one.

Answer (score 2):

Use `sklearn.preprocessing.scale`.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.scale.html

Here is an example.

```
>>> from sklearn import preprocessing
>>> import numpy as np
>>> X_train = np.array([[ 1., -1.,  2.],
...                     [ 2.,  0.,  0.],
...                     [ 0.,  1., -1.]])
>>> X_scaled = preprocessing.scale(X_train)
>>> X_scaled
array([[ 0.  ..., -1.22...,  1.33...],
       [ 1.22...,  0.  ..., -0.26...],
       [-1.22...,  1.22..., -1.06...]])
```

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#standardization-or-mean-removal-and-variance-scaling

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1,2,6], [3000,1000,2000]]).T  

A_means = np.mean(A, axis=0)
A_centr = A - A_means
A_norms = np.linalg.norm(A_centr, axis=0)

A_std = A_centr / A_norms
```