# List of lists into numpy array

Tags: python, list, numpy

How do I convert a simple list of lists into a numpy array? The rows are individual sublists and each row contains the elements in the sublist.

Answer (score 283):

If your list of lists contains lists with varying number of elements then the answer of Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams will not work. Instead there are at least 3 options:

1) Make an array of arrays:

```
x=[[1,2],[1,2,3],[1]]
y=numpy.array([numpy.array(xi) for xi in x])
type(y)
>>><type 'numpy.ndarray'>
type(y[0])
>>><type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

2) Make an array of lists:

```
x=[[1,2],[1,2,3],[1]]
y=numpy.array(x)
type(y)
>>><type 'numpy.ndarray'>
type(y[0])
>>><type 'list'>
```

3) First make the lists equal in length:

```
x=[[1,2],[1,2,3],[1]]
length = max(map(len, x))
y=numpy.array([xi+[None]*(length-len(xi)) for xi in x])
y
>>>array([[1, 2, None],
>>>       [1, 2, 3],
>>>       [1, None, None]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: `dtype=float` works too, it will convert `None` to `np.nan`, which may be useful.

Comment: On python 3.9, I had to use `(np.vectorize(len)(x)).max()` instead of `max(map(len, x))` on the third solution

Comment: And you get a warning: `VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
  return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)`

Answer (score 148):

```
>>> numpy.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]]) 
array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
```

Comment: this automatically convert a list of list in a 2D array because the length of all included lists are the same. Do you know how not to do that: make an array of list even if all the lists have the same length? Or is it possible to convert a 2D array in a 1D array of 1D array (efficiently I mean, no iterative method or python map stuff)

Comment: If that doesn't work for you because your sublists are not of even sizes, see [the following answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26224619/1449460).

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks I was confused after looking at the answer but your comment was helpful. I found out that my list of lists was jagged, when it wasn't supposed to be.

Comment: How fast is this with respect to the length of the argument? I am not seeing a good answer in the documentation?

Answer (score 63):

As this is the top search on Google for converting a list of lists into a Numpy array, I'll offer the following despite the question being 4 years old:

```
>>> x = [[1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1]]
>>> y = numpy.hstack(x)
>>> print(y)
[1 2 1 2 3 1]
```

When I first thought of doing it this way, I was quite pleased with myself because it's soooo simple.  However, after timing it with a larger list of lists, it is actually faster to do this:

```
>>> y = numpy.concatenate([numpy.array(i) for i in x])
>>> print(y)
[1 2 1 2 3 1]
```

Note that @Bastiaan's answer #1 doesn't make a single continuous list, hence I added the `concatenate`.

Anyway...I prefer the `hstack` approach for it's elegant use of Numpy.

Comment: while some people may be looking for this, I'm pretty sure the OP wanted a multi-dimensional nparr.

Answer (score 29):

It's as simple as:

```
>>> lists = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> np.array(lists)
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

Answer (score 9):

Again, after searching for the problem of converting nested lists with N levels into an N-dimensional array I found nothing, so here's my way around it:

```
import numpy as np

new_array=np.array([[[coord for coord in xk] for xk in xj] for xj in xi], ndmin=3) #this case for N=3
```

Comment: Note that if you already have the nested-lists structure, you don't need the `[...[...[...]]]` part. You just need to call `np.array`, with `ndmin=number-of-list-layers`. (though in my case I needed `ndmin=number-of-list-layers-minus-1` for some reason, else created an extra layer -- need to investigate)

Comment: Ah okay, the problem in my case is that for the deepest "list layer", the lists did not all have the same length, which caused `np.array` to just "wrap" those deepest-lists rather than convert them into numpy arrays.

Comment: `xi = [[[3, 4], [3, 4]], [[3, 4], [3, 4]]]` gives `array([[[3, 4],
        [3, 4]],

       [[3, 4],
        [3, 4]]])`. I only see the array at the outer layer here. I thought the question is about converting everything to a numpy array? Or did I choose a wrong example?

Answer (score 6):

The OP specified that "the rows are individual sublists and each row contains the elements in the sublist".

Assuming that the use of `numpy` is not prohibited (given that the flair numpy has been added in the OP), use `vstack`:

```
import numpy as np

list_of_lists= [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7 ,8, 9]]

array = np.vstack(list_of_lists)
# array([[1, 2, 3],
#        [4, 5, 6],
#        [7, 8, 9]])
```

or simpler (as mentioned in another answer),

```
array = np.array(list_of_lists)
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other answers, `np.vstack()` will let you convert your list-of-lists(nested list) into a 1-dimensional array of sublists. But if you are looking to convert the list of lists into a 2-dimensional numpy.ndarray. Then you can use the `numpy.asarray()` function.

For example, if you have a list of lists named `y_true` that looks like:

```
[[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0]]
<class 'list'>
```

This line `y_true = np.asarray(y_true)` will convert the list of lists into a 2-dimensional numpy ndarray that looks like:

```
 [[0 1 0]
  [1 0 0]
  [0 0 1]
  [1 0 0]
  [0 1 0]
  [0 0 1]
  [1 0 0]]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Additionally, you can also specify the `dtype` parameter like `np.asarray(y_true, dtype = float)` to have your array values in your desired data type.

Answer (score -5):

I had a list of lists of equal length. Even then `Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams`'s answer didn't work out for me. I got a 1-D numpy array whose elements are lists. If you faced the same problem, you can use the below method

Use `numpy.vstack`

```
import numpy as np

np_array = np.empty((0,4), dtype='float')
for i in range(10)
     row_data = ...   # get row_data as list
     np_array = np.vstack((np_array, np.array(row_data)))
```

Comment: why on earth would you keep stacking if you know that you have 10 lists, why not np.empty((10, 4)) and then just filling it up?

Answer (score -8):

Just use pandas

```py
list(pd.DataFrame(listofstuff).melt().values)
```

this only works for a list of lists

if you have a list of list of lists you might want to try something along the lines of

```py
lists(pd.DataFrame(listofstuff).melt().apply(pd.Series).melt().values)
```

Comment: The question was about numpy, not pandas.