# list of lists into numpy array - wrong output

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I am pretty new to Python, I have a list of lists, which when printed this is the following output, lets call it list1:

```
[['2012-09-01', '25,922'], ['2013-09-01', '41,733'], ['2014-09-01', '37,037'], ['2015-09-01', '39,510'], ['2016-09-01', '53,394']]
```

Then I am converting to a numpy array, just like in this thread [List of lists into numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346336/list-of-lists-into-numpy-array)

and when I do:

```
print(numpy.array(list1))
```

I get the following output:

```
[['2012-09-01' '25,922']
 ['2013-09-01' '41,733']
 ['2014-09-01' '37,037']
 ['2015-09-01' '39,510']
 ['2016-09-01' '53,394']]
```

I was expecting the same output as the previous one, just like in the other thread. What stupid thing am I doing here?

When I print both types of the lists I get the following output:

```
<class 'list'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

So its seems to be doing the right thing.

Thank you!

Comment: but on the other forum the output has comma dividing the elements in each list as well as separating the lists themselves

Comment: I want to use this array to plot in matplotlib, but with this format I dont know how to separate dates from the rest of the values

Comment: Okay, thanks for the explanation guys, didnt know about that.
I will accept Wasi as answer as he also edited my code haha. Have a good day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outputs are essentially same, the only difference is python prints list in one format and array in another. But if you want to see a `list`-like output, you can do the following:

```
print(numpy.array(list1).tolist())
```

Though it doesn't make sense to me because you are converting the list to array and want to print in `list`-like format.

Answer (score 0):

That is just how numpy arrays are printed. The list is still the same eg.

```
print(numpy.array(list1)[0][1])
```

and

```
print(list1[0][1])
```

are the same.