# python converting nested list to array shape (x,y)

Tags: python

Here is the info on the data:

> len(train_x)
>
> 43907
>
> len(train_x[0])
>
> 120

At this moment,

> the result of train_x.shape and train_x[0].shape = AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'

How can I convert the list to array, so that

> train_x.shape = (43907, 120)

Thanks a lot!

I have tried some method:

> y = np.array([np.array(xi) for xi in train_x])
>
> y.shape
>
> (43907,)
>
> y = np.asarray(train_x)
>
> y.shape
>
> (43907,)

train_x

> ...,
>          list([0.5079, 0.53121, 0.48361, 0.43715, 0.23894, 0.40985, 0.37101, 0.52262, 0.3558, 0.32028, 0.07165, 0.22726, 0.1828, 0.33434, 0.22724, 0.58681, 0.60266, 0.54746, 0.54243, 0.27596, 0.48267, 0.44198, 0.61634, 0.40842, 0.36773, 0.08, 0.25968, 0.20736, 0.4081, 0.26364, 0.43949, 0.40627, 0.34249, 0.41082, 0.29823, 0.41726, 0.3349, 0.40235, 0.36406, 0.32254, 0.1037, 0.28708, 0.24023, 0.37453, 0.28247, 0.6889, 0.64081, 0.5699, 0.69185, 0.59155, 0.65528, 0.57795, 0.64536, 0.60209, 0.58496, 0.29947, 0.62166, 0.52717, 0.6641, 0.56016, 0.44234, 0.50816, 0.51885, 0.4832, 0.18316, 0.4146, 0.33292, 0.50479, 0.31084, 0.28013, 0.06714, 0.26984, 0.12609, 0.33334, 0.17912, 0.53691, 0.60331, 0.61581, 0.59752, 0.24429, 0.50457, 0.40295, 0.59399, 0.38408, 0.34765, 0.09223, 0.35618, 0.17109, 0.42679, 0.23766, 0.41467, 0.3831, 0.36008, 0.43135, 0.24159, 0.40538, 0.31992, 0.37393, 0.34129, 0.29538, 0.09859, 0.32734, 0.17516, 0.36731, 0.23401, 0.63889, 0.60933, 0.59681, 0.67709, 0.43071, 0.61608, 0.52587, 0.58346, 0.54974, 0.49239, 0.20944, 0.56235, 0.33494, 0.58968, 0.42295]),
>          list([0.44562, 0.4337, 0.44278, 0.3224, 0.20899, 0.32632, 0.29239, 0.41387, 0.32087, 0.30168, 0.08165, 0.22109, 0.17525, 0.26691, 0.20498, 0.54586, 0.55545, 0.54536, 0.41838, 0.25996, 0.4172, 0.37677, 0.5596, 0.39001, 0.37804, 0.11458, 0.28325, 0.21854, 0.33375, 0.25278, 0.3771, 0.3383, 0.30371, 0.31716, 0.29712, 0.3303, 0.27284, 0.3175, 0.33599, 0.32316, 0.17167, 0.30562, 0.27194, 0.31794, 0.29298, 0.6748, 0.64904, 0.63219, 0.65454, 0.60501, 0.61411, 0.56783, 0.63976, 0.61265, 0.62258, 0.50435, 0.61295, 0.56444, 0.65123, 0.58579, 0.40265, 0.41731, 0.41685, 0.3587, 0.19036, 0.32674, 0.25677, 0.39837, 0.29952, 0.2852, 0.08595, 0.27498, 0.14699, 0.29198, 0.1872, 0.50656, 0.54926, 0.54703, 0.48424, 0.27635, 0.42882, 0.34395, 0.52142, 0.39228, 0.3695, 0.13538, 0.36894, 0.21603, 0.39077, 0.26227, 0.36863, 0.30839, 0.28054, 0.32331, 0.27293, 0.3181, 0.25168, 0.28213, 0.32865, 0.3082, 0.1463, 0.33453, 0.22056, 0.3328, 0.26219, 0.61468, 0.57264, 0.53805, 0.62109, 0.52939, 0.57874, 0.51463, 0.55062, 0.56618, 0.55165, 0.35363, 0.56063, 0.45399, 0.59937, 0.4995]),
>          list([0.42686, 0.52863, 0.53296, 0.40155, 0.18718, 0.32846, 0.36395, 0.4877, 0.30638, 0.26646, 0.0574, 0.17585, 0.14181, 0.27585, 0.18107, 0.55571, 0.66385, 0.67141, 0.50482, 0.26711, 0.41882, 0.46826, 0.58885, 0.41483, 0.36966, 0.09126, 0.26158, 0.21532, 0.35672, 0.26033, 0.36466, 0.38593, 0.32948, 0.37587, 0.25761, 0.34377, 0.31994, 0.34747, 0.31665, 0.28035, 0.10506, 0.24764, 0.2124, 0.3221, 0.24991, 0.65471, 0.68596, 0.61005, 0.69722, 0.56871, 0.62323, 0.61021, 0.62214, 0.58637, 0.55695, 0.31264, 0.56399, 0.49827, 0.64056, 0.53781, 0.38984, 0.48815, 0.50692, 0.4368, 0.15727, 0.35157, 0.31332, 0.45288, 0.27907, 0.25549, 0.05977, 0.23205, 0.11038, 0.28667, 0.15373, 0.49773, 0.61135, 0.60841, 0.55314, 0.22866, 0.44204, 0.41888, 0.54144, 0.371, 0.34695, 0.09296, 0.32596, 0.16407, 0.38, 0.21598, 0.35139, 0.33565, 0.30974, 0.36287, 0.25204, 0.33579, 0.28758, 0.30216, 0.31353, 0.28133, 0.12115, 0.30722, 0.19914, 0.32828, 0.24022, 0.61315, 0.60307, 0.57119, 0.68241, 0.57468, 0.61035, 0.54417, 0.55351, 0.5807, 0.55985, 0.3485, 0.58748, 0.4884, 0.62484, 0.52738])], dtype=object)

Comment: have you tried `np.array(train_x).reshape(43907, 120)`

Comment: This question has a duplicate here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346336/list-of-lists-into-numpy-array

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Or, in one call, `np.reshape(train_x, (43907, 120))`...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes, the result : ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 43907 into shape (43907,120)

Comment: Eh? Just `np.array(train_x)` should suffice. The shape is already correct, innit?

Comment: @Amadan np.array(train_x) > (43907,). But I want (43907, 120) :(

Comment: Show how your `train_x` looks like. Because if it's just list of lists... `np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]).shape` is `(2, 4)`, not `(2,)`. EDIT: unless your rows have differing lengths, in which case you have to fix that first.

Comment: Are lists in train_x of varying length? Are there lists longer than 120?

Comment: @seed They are fixed at 120.

Comment: What about 
`length = 120

y=numpy.array([xi[:length]+[None]*(length-len(xi)) for xi in x])`
Does it work?

Comment: @seed It works! now I get train_x.shape = (43907, 120)

Comment: It means that there are varying list sizes in your list after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all lists are of equal length,

```
y = numpy.array(train_x)
```

will do the job.

If there are lists of varying lengths, the following code

```
length = 120
y=numpy.array([xi[:length]+[None]*(length-len(xi)) for xi in x_train])
```

will cut all longer lists at 120 and add None to shorter lists to get an array of desired shape.

Comment: You are correct. Finally, I figured out actually there are some rows missing one dimension.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
np.array(list(train_x)).shape
```

answer would be (43907, 120) if list has equal length elements inside it.

otherwise, it will be:

(43907,)