# Turning nested lists into a numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

I've got some data which I've arranged in the form of `[[[0, 1], [2, 3]], [[4, 5], [6,7]]]`, e.g. 3 dimensions. However, the function I'm using requires a `numpy` array to work, so I need to convert it from nested lists into one. Whenever I try though I always find that the fist two layers of lists convert, but the final one doesn't? e.g. If I try to print:

```
print(data)          # Prints a numpy.ndarray
print(data[0][0])    # Prints a numpy.ndarray
print(data[0][0][0]) # Prints a list
```

I've tried a few different methods to convert it, but they all return the data like this? Anyone got any ideas what I can do?

Comment: Your inner-layer lists probably aren't all the same size.

Comment: This is covered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346336/list-of-lists-into-numpy-array

Answer (score 2):

A bit confused on what your data refers to, but given

```
import numpy as np

x = [[[0, 1], [2, 3]], [[4, 5], [6,7]]]

# convert to numpy.ndarray
y = np.asarray(x)
print(type(y)) # y is now a numpy.ndarray

# Checking dimensions
print(y.shape)  # (2,2,2) - 3D array
```