# Converting a List of Lists into a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

Before you mark this question as a duplicate, please read through the entire post...

I have a list of lists that looks something like...

```
>>> print(list_of_lists)
[[3, 3, 7, 8, 5], [9, 3, 3, 3, 3], [9, 10, 11, 3, 23, 3, 3], [20, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [20, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]]
```

I want to convert this list of lists into an array. However, when I do:

```
potential_numpy_array = numpy.array(list_of_lists)
```

or:

```
potential_numpy_array = numpy.asarray(list_of_lists)
```

I get something stranger:

```
>>> print(potential_numpy_array)
[list([3, 3, 17, 18, 16]) list([20, 3, 3, 3, 3]) list([20, 5, 6, 3, 12, 3, 3]) list([9, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]) list([9, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3])]
```

I've looked at many other questions but did not find an answer that could solve this problem.

Could someone please help me identify the source of confusion?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use numpy with jagged lists, it will only cause you more of a headache later

Comment: Do you want it to be a numpy array with numpy arrays within it?

Comment: @user3483203 Okay, should I "pad" the lists?

Comment: Check here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346336/list-of-lists-into-numpy-array/26224619#26224619

Comment: @Hadus A list of numpy arrays is what I want (although a numpy array of numpy arrays would be fine too)

Comment: @RohanBhowmik that's a valid approach, yes.

Comment: This is still a duplicate, there are many answers about making a 2d array of jagged list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a list of numpy arrays:

```
np_arrays = []

for array in arrays:
    np_arrays.append(numpy.array(array))
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the help of fellow stackOverflow users, I realized the list was "jagged" and needed to be padded. An example of a jagged list is:

```
[ [1,2],
  [1,3,2],
  [1] ]
```

I needed:

```
[ [1,2,0],
  [1,3,2],
  [1,0,0] ]
```

Since I am using TensorFlow and keras, I can just do:

```
test_data = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(test_data,
                                                    value=word_index["<PAD>"],
                                                    padding='post',
                                                    maxlen=12)
```