# Python - convert list of lists into matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, arraylist

I am using python, I have a list which contains inside it group of lists 
how can I convert it into one matrix?

for example,

```
Root_List = [list1  list2  list3]
list1 = [1 2 3]
list2 = [1 5 9]
list3 = [2 4 1]
```

I need matrix to have below value

```
[
1 2 3
1 5 9
2 4 1
]
```

Any idea? 
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `keras` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Answer (score 2):

If they all have the same length, try this:

```
import numpy as np
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [1,5,9]
list3 = [2,4,1]
Root_List = [list1, list2,list3]
np.array(Root_List)
```

Answer (score 0):

A matrix is a list of list.

Best practice is to first define your root list, then append sublists you want:

```
Root_List = []
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
Root_List.append(list1)
list2 = [1, 5, 9]
Root_List.append(list2)
list3 = [2, 4, 1]
Root_List.append(list3)
```

As suggested by @Antonio Manrique, you can also convert it using numpy to benefit matrix calculation functions of this lib. [This answer answer how to convert a python list of list to a numpy matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346336/list-of-lists-into-numpy-array).