# please explain me this code about matrix in python

Tags: python-3.x

Hey I was trying to write a program to find the sum of two matrices A and B and store the sum in another matrix C but I am not getting this code of Declaring Matrices with for loop

```
r = int(input('Enter no. of rows of matrix A'))
c = int(input('Enter the number of colm. of matrix B'))
r1 = int(input('Enter the number of rows of Matrix B'))
c1 = int(input('Enter the number of colm. of Matrix B'))
#declaring  of matrices
A = [[0 for x in range(c)]for x in range(r)]
B = [[0 for x in range(c1)]for x in range(r1)]
```

Comment: Read about `list comprehension` in Python.

Comment: And something like this question that explains how to go from list of lists to numpy array/matrix: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10346336/9987623