# How do I convert the list of lists to a NumPy array and get the full size?

Tags: python, keras, nltk

When I have tried to run this code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(len(set(text_words)), 100,input_length=8555))
model.compile('rmsprop', 'mse')
output_array = model.predict(b)
```

I got this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected embedding_1_input to have shape (8555,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

What is going wrong in this section?

I am using *NumPy array* data. Variable `b` is the NumPy array data in my code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of lists into numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346336/list-of-lists-into-numpy-array)

Comment: Numpy has a `flatten` method for this https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert a list of lists to a numpy array then print its shape and size:

```
import numpy as np 

numpy_array = np.array(list_of_lists)
print("shape:", numpy_array.shape," size", numpy_array.size)
```