# list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple: TypeError - Python

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda

I'm trying to invoke a AWS lambda function which is written in python, It takes a 2D array as an input but while parsing this array the python code is throwing the following error 
 "list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple: TypeError"

Code which is parsing this list

```py
# Input:
#    "utilityRates": [[0, 600, 0.2, 1, 366], [600, 900, 0.15, 1, 366], [900, 1440, 0.3, 1, 366]]

    TempElectricityRate = request["utilityRates"]
    print(TempElectricityRate)
    ElectricityRate = numpy.zeros((3,5))
    for x in range(0, 3):
        ElectricityRate[x,0] = TempElectricityRate[x,0]
        ElectricityRate[x,1] = TempElectricityRate[x,1]
        ElectricityRate[x,2] = TempElectricityRate[x,2]
        ElectricityRate[x,3] = TempElectricityRate[x,3]
        ElectricityRate[x,4] = TempElectricityRate[x,4]
```

Comment: Looks like `TempElectricityRate` is a Python list. If so the you should index it like `TempElectricityRate[x][0]`.

Comment: Thanks @Poolka. That helped.
And also as you can see in the code I'm explicitly converting list into 2d array. Is there a builtin function in Python that would do that for me?

Comment: `numpy` has a lot to offer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346336/list-of-lists-into-numpy-array