# Convert a list to an 3 dimensional numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list, which consist collection of differently shaped 2 dimensional numpy arrays inside it. It looks like this.

[image]

My goal is to convert this to a 3d numpy array so that its structure is something like this

```
[ 
  [[ ]
   [ ]
    :
     ],

  [[ ]
   [ ]
    :
     ],

    :
]
```

or in words

```
[

 two dimensional array 1,
 two dimensional array 2,
 two dimensional array 3,
       :
       :
]
```

I tried doing

```
arr = np.array(garbage)
```

that gives me an array but it is not structured as I described it. Its shape comes out to be `(40336,)`

I have to pass the array to a RNN. Do I have to pad zeros for all internal 2 dimensional arrays so that they are of same shape which will make the outer array of the three dimensional shape that I want?

Comment: try appending all smaller lists in to a list and then apply np.array on that list

Comment: The individual list ( if you are referring to inner two dimensional arrays)  are distinct observations. I need them to be as a separate observation so, cannot append them

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346336/list-of-lists-into-numpy-array

Comment: It won't be really 3 dimensional unless the arrays are even. You may get an array of dtype 'object' with uneven arrays inside. So yeah, padding is definitely necessary particularly for RNNs.

Comment: if anyone has this problem in future refer [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/48796/how-to-feed-lstm-with-different-input-array-sizes) for the solution to this problem