# How can I get Index of any element in python numpy array that has list inside?

Tags: python, numpy, nlp

I have a numpy array that has lists inside. this is my numpy array structure

```py
array([list(['記', 'hk', '超抵', '玩', '轉台', '優惠', '無限', '任用']),
       list(['学生', '个人', '兼职', '援交', '加']), list(['轉', '台大', '優惠']), ...,
       list(['af', 'ia']), list(['交換', 'sourc']),
       list(['美食', 'cf', 'asm', '幾分'])], dtype=object)
```

The i've used

```py
np.where(Arr=="ia")
```

but i didn't get any index return. this is my output

```py
(array([], dtype=int64),)
```

How can i access the element index like normal numpy array?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need the array to stay an array of lists instead of a 2d array? If so - numpy won't be able to find this automatically for you, you would have to search for it manually

Comment: even i convert it to array([array(["string])]) it still doesn't work for me.

Comment: when i convert it to 2d array it get something like this:array([array(['記', 'hk', '超抵', '玩', '轉台', '優惠', '無限', '任用'], dtype='<U2'),
       array(['学生', '个人', '兼职', '援交', '加'], dtype='<U2'),
       array(['轉', '台大', '優惠'], dtype='<U2'), ...,
       array(['af', 'ia'], dtype='<U2'),
       array(['交換', 'sourc'], dtype='<U5'),
       array(['美食', 'cf', 'asm', '幾分'], dtype='<U3')], dtype=object)

Comment: And I don't need my array to stay as array of list what i want i just to acess the index of the element inside.

Comment: Since the lists inside that array vary in length, you have, effectively a list of lists.  `numpy` methods won't help you.

Comment: That `where` just returns the location of the `True` values in `Arr=="ia"`.  That is probably a 1d array all `False`, because none of the lists match string.  They may contain that string, but doesn't test for that.

Comment: Do you need the index of the list containing the element or the index of the element in the list or both?

Comment: both but with the index of the list that contain that element also fine for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NumPy only works with arrays and list of the same length.

The best you can do is make all the lists of the same size appending `None` elements and then use NumPy functions. The drawback of using this approach is that, if there is a list that is much larger than the others, the filled array will use a lot memory to save dummy `None` values.

Taking inspiration from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26224619/16401339), you can use the following code

```
a = np.array([list(['記', 'hk', '超抵', '玩', '轉台', '優惠', '無限', '任用']),
       list(['学生', '个人', '兼职', '援交', '加']), list(['轉', '台大', '優惠']),
       list(['af', 'ia']), list(['交換', 'sourc']),
       list(['美食', 'cf', 'asm', '幾分'])], dtype=object)
max_length = max(len(l) for l in a)
filled_array = np.array([l + [None] * (max_length-len(l)) for l in a])
print(np.where(filled_array=="ia"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [213]: Arr=np.array([list(['記', 'hk', '超抵', '玩', '轉台', '優惠', '無限', '任用']),
     ...:        list(['学生', '个人', '兼职', '援交', '加']), list(['轉', '台大', '優惠'])
     ...: ,
     ...:        list(['af', 'ia']), list(['交換', 'sourc']),
     ...:        list(['美食', 'cf', 'asm', '幾分'])], dtype=object)
In [214]: Arr
Out[214]: 
array([list(['記', 'hk', '超抵', '玩', '轉台', '優惠', '無限', '任用']),
       list(['学生', '个人', '兼职', '援交', '加']), list(['轉', '台大', '優惠']),
       list(['af', 'ia']), list(['交換', 'sourc']),
       list(['美食', 'cf', 'asm', '幾分'])], dtype=object)
```

Using regular Python list methods:

```
In [215]: for i,l in enumerate(Arr):
     ...:     print(i, 'ia' in l)
     ...: 
0 False
1 False
2 False
3 True
4 False
5 False

In [216]: for i,l in enumerate(Arr):
     ...:     if 'ia' in l:
     ...:         print(i,l.index('ia'))
     ...: 
3 1
```

An object dtype array is basically a list, with few, if any, advantages.  `numpy` also does not have much of its own string methods.