# np.float64 and dtype=object can not be serialized

Tags: python, json, numpy, serialization, json-deserialization

i have the below posted list and it contais lists, so it is a list of lists, and i have a webservice that returns `return jsonify(resultsDict)`. the problem i am facing is when i run the App i recieve either of the error messages posted below.
as shown in the code below, i tried to set `dtype=np.float64` and `dtype=object`, but each of them generates an error associated to it as shown below in the code.
please let me know how to fix it

**attempt_1**

```
resultsDict={
    "extras": {
        "pvTreatment":np.array(pvTreatment,dtype=np.float64).tolist(),
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }
}
    
**error associated**:

    ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (7,) + inhomogeneous part.
```

**attempt_2**

```
resultsDict = {
    "extras": {
        "pvTreatment":np.array(pvTreatment,dtype=object).tolist(),
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }
}   
    
**error associated**:

    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
    TypeError: Object of type float32 is not JSON serializable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I try to make an array with two arrays that differ in length I get your kind of error:

```
In [186]: np.array([np.ones((3)), np.zeros((4))],float)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [186], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 np.array([np.ones((3)), np.zeros((4))],float)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (2,) + inhomogeneous part.
```

I can make an `object` dtype array:

```
In [187]: np.array([np.ones((3)), np.zeros((4))],object)
Out[187]: array([array([1., 1., 1.]), array([0., 0., 0., 0.])], dtype=object)
```

But when I use `tolist` I get a list with two arrays:

```
In [188]: np.array([np.ones((3)), np.zeros((4))],object).tolist()
Out[188]: [array([1., 1., 1.]), array([0., 0., 0., 0.])]
```

Arrays are not JSON serializable.

If the inner arrays were changed to lists, we'd get a list of lists:

```
In [191]: np.array([np.ones((3)).tolist(), np.zeros((4)).tolist()],object).tolist()
Out[191]: [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

For this kind of thing, avoid arrays - both for the outer list and the inner ones.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use make lists equal in size first (if they don't differ by orders of magnitude) as in this example - [List of lists into numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346336/list-of-lists-into-numpy-array)

In this way you will have an easier time deserializing it into list of lists. Also You can use external libraries like pickle if you want.

Comment: but the main list contains lists that differ in size for example [[1,2,3,4],[5],[6,7],....]?