# Python list converting oddly to NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a python `list`:

```
[[([1, 20230112060000], [10000, 20230112060000]),
  ([1, 20230108060000], [7000, 20230109060000]),
  ([3, 20221229060000], [6929, 20221229060000]),
  ([1, 20221227060000], [3900, 20221227060000]),
  ([1, 20221226060000], [6500, 20221226060000]),
  ([1, 20221221060000], [4400, 20221222060000]),
  ([1, 20221216060000], [3888, 20221216060000]),
  ([1, 20221205060000], [5998, 20221205060000]),
  ([1, 20221128060000], [5000, 20221128060000]),
  ([1, 20221127060000], [5000, 20221127060000]),
  ([1, 20221123060000], [5666, 20221123060000]),
  ([1, 20221122060000], [6000, 20221122060000]),
  ([1, 20221120060000], [4300, 20221120060000]),
  ([1, 20221118060000], [4998, 20221118060000]),
  ([1, 20221028050000], [2700, 20221028050000]),
  ([1, 20221027050000], [5000, 20221027050000]),
  ([1, 20221022050000], [4300, 20221022050000]),
  ([1, 20221019050000], [4498, 20221019050000]),
  ([1, 20221018050000], [3500, 20221018050000]),
  ([2, 20221015050000], [3899, 20221015050000]),
  ([1, 20221011050000], [4500, 20221011050000]),
  ([2, 20221008050000], [4850, 20221008050000]),
  ([2, 20221007050000], [5898, 20221007050000]),
  ([1, 20221004050000], [7499, 20221004050000]),
  ([1, 20221001050000], [3400, 20221001050000]),
...
 [],
 [([2, 20230206060000], [357500, 20230206060000])],
 [([2, 20230206060000], [357500, 20230206060000]),
  ([6, 20230205060000], [353833, 20230205060000])],
 ...]
```

But when I try to convert it to a NumPy array something weird happens:

```
import numpy as np
a = [...] # the above list
b = np.array(a)
```

`b`:

```
array([list([([1, 20230112060000], [10000, 20230112060000]), ([1, 20230108060000], [7000, 20230109060000]), ([3, 20221229060000], [6929, 20221229060000]), ([1, 20221227060000], [3900, 20221227060000]), ([1, 20221226060000], [6500, 20221226060000]), ([1, 20221221060000], [4400, 20221222060000]), ([1, 20221216060000], [3888, 20221216060000]), ([1, 20221205060000], [5998, 20221205060000]), ([1, 20221128060000], [5000, 20221128060000]), ([1, 20221127060000], [5000, 20221127060000]), ([1, 20221123060000], [5666, 20221123060000]), ([1, 20221122060000], [6000, 20221122060000]), ([1, 20221120060000], [4300, 20221120060000]), ([1, 20221118060000], [4998, 20221118060000]), ([1, 20221028050000], [2700, 20221028050000]), ([1, 20221027050000], [5000, 20221027050000]), ([1, 20221022050000], [4300, 20221022050000]), ([1, 20221019050000], [4498, 20221019050000]), ([1, 20221018050000], [3500, 20221018050000]), ([2, 20221015050000], [3899, 20221015050000]), ([1, 20221011050000], [4500, 20221011050000]), ([2, 20221008050000], [4850, 20221008050000]), ([2, 20221007050000], [5898, 20221007050000]), ([1, 20221004050000], [7499, 20221004050000]), ([1, 20221001050000], [3400, 20221001050000]), ([1, 20220928050000], [5000, 20220929050000]), ([1, 20220926050000], [3000, 20220926050000]), ([1, 20220925050000], [4500, 20220925050000]), ([1, 20220922050000], [4000, 20220922050000]), ([1, 20220920050000], [5000, 20220920050000]), ([1, 20220916050000], [8000, 20220916050000]), ([2, 20220915050000], [6625, 20220915050000]), ([2, 20220914050000], [4500, 20220914050000]), ([1, 20220903050000], [10000, 20220903050000]), ([1, 20220821050000], [8600, 20220821050000]), ([2, 20220820050000], [37500, 20220820050000]), ([1, 20220819050000], [30000, 20220819050000]), ([2, 20220818050000], [13999, 20220818050000]), ([1, 20220816050000], [4000, 20220817050000]), ([1, 20220815050000], [4000, 20220815050000])]),
       list([]), list([([1, 20230112060000], [10000, 20230112060000])]),
       ...,
       list([([1, 20230123060000], [5745, 20230123060000]), ([1, 20230105060000], [13000, 20230105060000]), ([1, 20221228060000], [6000, 20221228060000]), ([2, 20221227060000], [6000, 20221227060000]), ([1, 20221222060000], [8571, 20221222060000]), ([1, 20221218060000], [8250, 20221218060000]), ([1, 20221216060000], [8000, 20221216060000]), ([1, 20221213060000], [7500, 20221213060000]), ([1, 20221210060000], [3500, 20221210060000]), ([1, 20221109060000], [6500, 20221109060000])]),
       list([([1, 20230123060000], [5745, 20230123060000]), ([1, 20230105060000], [13000, 20230105060000]), ([1, 20221228060000], [6000, 20221228060000]), ([2, 20221227060000], [6000, 20221227060000]), ([1, 20221222060000], [8571, 20221222060000]), ([1, 20221218060000], [8250, 20221218060000]), ([1, 20221216060000], [8000, 20221216060000]), ([1, 20221213060000], [7500, 20221213060000]), ([1, 20221210060000], [3500, 20221210060000]), ([1, 20221109060000], [6500, 20221109060000]), ([1, 20220909050000], [9999, 20220909050000])]),
       list([([1, 20230123060000], [5745, 20230123060000]), ([1, 20230105060000], [13000, 20230105060000]), ([1, 20221228060000], [6000, 20221228060000]), ([2, 20221227060000], [6000, 20221227060000]), ([1, 20221222060000], [8571, 20221222060000]), ([1, 20221218060000], [8250, 20221218060000]), ([1, 20221216060000], [8000, 20221216060000]), ([1, 20221213060000], [7500, 20221213060000]), ([1, 20221210060000], [3500, 20221210060000]), ([1, 20221109060000], [6500, 20221109060000]), ([1, 20220909050000], [9999, 20220909050000]), ([1, 20220901050000], [8444, 20220901050000])])],
      dtype=object)
```

For some reason, the tuples and the lists are not converted properly. Because of this, `b` does not function like a normal NumPy array because all of the items are objects. I know I could go through and covert all of the `tuples` to `lists`, but is there a way to force NumPy to convert everything properly?

By the way, by converted properly I mean instead of:

```
array([list([()])])
```

It should be converted like:

```
array([[[]]])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of lists into numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346336/list-of-lists-into-numpy-array)

Comment: "For some reason, the tuples and the lists are not converted properly." What do you think should be the result instead? **Why**? Can you demonstrate the problem with a smaller input? Please read [ask] and [mre].

Comment: I think the problem might be because not all of your list are the same size e.g. `np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])` is fine, but `np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]])` caused `Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences` warning. Either filter or add default value to the list such that every element is the same size first (The problem is `list([])` part - probably)

Comment: Your input appears to be jagged. NumPy doesn't do jagged arrays - strict shape requirements are crucial to NumPy's efficiency.

Comment: Oh, so I have to pad the individual arrays so they are all the same length?

Comment: That would be one way to handle things. Whether it's appropriate for your use case, we can't tell.

Comment: @catasaurus Yes, you have to. Or to remove them from the list. Or to shorten all the others... Numpy array are hyper-rectangular (meaning that they have a regular size in all dimensions).

Comment: That `list([])` stands out like a sore thumb!  It isn't the mix of tuples versus lists, it's their size that varies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As correctly pointed out by `Wakeme UpNow`, your issue is in the fact that your lists are not of the same size. The key point you should understand in working with `NumPy` is that it gains its' performance from making some premises about your data, i.e.,:

- 1. It is numeric
- 2. It is of the same type
- 3. All the sub-arrays are of the same length

If you break one of these premises, you automatically loose all the gains which otherwise you'd get from `NumPy` use, as it will fall back to a purly `pythonic` behavior (i.e., by `dtype=object`).

In-depth `NumPy` discussion may be found [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.00-introduction-to-numpy.html).

So a way to fix this issue of yours would be to use numeric values, of the *same* data type, of arrays of the the *same* length.

Cheers