# What happens when using 3 indexes to slice a 4-dimensional array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to understand why the accuracy of my algorithm has suddenly changed quite dramatically. One small change I did what that I added a forth `:` when I discovered that I was using only 3 indexes when standardizing my 4-dimensional train/test set. And now I'm curious - would the below old/new code do the same? If not, how does indexing into a 4-dimensional array using only 3 indexes work?

**Old:**

```
   # standardize all non-binary variables
   channels = 14 # int(X.shape[1])
   mu_f     = np.zeros(shape=channels)
   sigma_f  = np.zeros(shape=channels)

   for i in range(channels):
      mu_f[i]    = np.mean(X_train[:,i,:])
      sigma_f[i] = np.std(X_train[:,i,:])   

   for i in range(channels):
      X_train[:, i, :]  -= mu_f[i]   
      X_test[:, i, :]   -= mu_f[i]

      if (sigma_f[i] != 0):
         X_train[:, i, :]  /= sigma_f[i]
         X_test[:, i, :]   /= sigma_f[i]
```

**New:**

```
   # standardize all non-binary variables
   channels = 14
   mu_f     = np.zeros(shape=channels)
   sigma_f  = np.zeros(shape=channels)

   for i in range(channels):
      mu_f[i]    = np.mean(X_train[:,i,:,:])
      sigma_f[i] = np.std(X_train[:,i,:,:])   

   for i in range(channels):
      X_train[:, i, :, :]  -= mu_f[i]   
      X_test[:, i, :, :]   -= mu_f[i]

      if (sigma_f[i] != 0):
         X_train[:, i, :, :]  /= sigma_f[i]
         X_test[:, i, :, :]   /= sigma_f[i]
```

Comment: Do you want to know why it is slower or how you can speed up things? ... because almost everyting can be vectorized in your code which should boost performance ...

Comment: That would be great! It would make more sense if you added an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29418031/standardization-preprocessing-for-4-dimensional-array instead.

Comment: To answer your question, yes, they both do the exact same thing. You could actually leave out all the trailing `:` and would still get the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why the extra `:` makes a difference.  It doesn't when I do time tests on a simple `np.mean(X[:,1])` v `np.mean(X,1,:,:]`, etc.

As for `plonser's` suggestion that you can vectorize the whole thing, the key is realizing that `mean` and `std` take some added parameters.  Check their docs and play around with sample arrays.

```
Xmean = np.mean(X,axis=(0,2,3),keepdims=True)
X -= Xmean
X /= Xmean
```

Comment: and he names his variable `X_train`.  :)  It's just an illustration.

Comment: Thanks. Are you also certain that my old code vs. my new code returns the same result for different kinds of values in `X_train`?

Comment: No.  It's possible I've missed some nuances in what you are trying do.  You need to set up parallel functions and test them - both for values and speed.