# Iterate through columns of an array to standardize data

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop

So I wrote a function to standardize my data but I'm having trouble making it work. I want to iterate through an array of my data and standardize it

Here's my function

I've tried Transposing my arr but it still doesn't work?

```
def Scaling(arr,data):    
    scaled=[[]]   
    for a in arr.T:
        scaled = ((a-data.mean())/(data.std()))
        scaled = np.asarray(scaled)
    return scaled
```

When I run my code I only get a 1D array as the output instead of 10D.

Comment: A bit out of topic, but you could use zscore from scipy: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.zscore.html

Comment: 10D or a shape with 10 columns? And could you please post a sample input and output?

Comment: Please add more information. What is data, how is this function called, what is arr? A quick google revealed multiple other SO answers like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544292/how-do-i-standardize-a-matrix/40951248

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `data.mean()` and `data.std()` are aggregated constants or scalars, consider running the needed arithmetic operation *directly* on entire array without any `for` loops. Each constant will be operated on each column of array in a vectorized operation:

```
def Scaling(arr,data):    
    return (arr.T-data.mean())/(data.std())
```

Your current `for` loop only outputs the last array assignment of loop. You initialize an empty nested list but do not ever append to it. In fact you re-assign and re-define *scaled* to an array with each iteration. Ideally you append arrays to a collection to concatenate together outside loop. Nonetheless, this type of operation is not needed with simple matrix algebra.

---

To demonstrate with random, seeded data (can be revised with OP's actual data) see below with an exaggerated sequential input array to show end calculations:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(12919)
data = np.arange(10)
arr = np.concatenate([np.ones((5, 1)),
                      np.ones((5, 1))+1,
                      np.ones((5, 1))+2,
                      np.ones((5, 1))+3,
                      np.ones((5, 1))+4], axis=1)

def Scaling(arr,data):    
    return (arr.T-data.mean())/(data.std())

new_arr = Scaling(arr, data)

print(arr)
# [[1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
#  [1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
#  [1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
#  [1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
#  [1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]]

print(new_arr)
# [[-1.21854359 -1.21854359 -1.21854359 -1.21854359 -1.21854359]
#  [-0.87038828 -0.87038828 -0.87038828 -0.87038828 -0.87038828]
#  [-0.52223297 -0.52223297 -0.52223297 -0.52223297 -0.52223297]
#  [-0.17407766 -0.17407766 -0.17407766 -0.17407766 -0.17407766]
#  [ 0.17407766  0.17407766  0.17407766  0.17407766  0.17407766]]
```

[Pyfiddle demo](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/6e692fae-a605-4eab-a5b8-08343c1d6faa/?i=true) *(click Run at top for output on right)*

Comment: Thank you it kind of works I'm getting the correct dimensions now, however, when I try to scale my test set with the means and std from the training set my results don't make sense </3